# Using WSL git with Windows integration

Tags: git, github, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I cannot get `git-credential-manager.exe` to operate with WSL (latest Ubuntu distro). I see various questions on Stackoverflow about this but *none* answer this for me.

My situation is simple. Everything is up to date.
`git` is installed in WSL.
`git is already the newest version (1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.1).`
Git for Windows is installed in Windows (Git for Windows v2.31.1, "Latest update: March 27th 2021").
Even worse: I have completely reinstalled Windows and then setup WSL and put a new Ubuntu instance onto it, and Windows integration with git *still* completely fails, so if I'm doing something wrong, I'd really appreciate knowing what that is!

Now, in WSL, I have setup the git-credential-manager to use Git for Windows. `sudo vi /usr/bin/git-credential-manager`, then add:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager.exe" $@
```

Save the file, then `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/git-credential-manager`
ok, so everything is (supposedly) setup. Inside my git project, I type `git push -u origin master`.

The Git for Windows credential manager pops open asking me for my credentials, so I input them. Then it all fails:

```
Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

I can manually input my username and password on the command line, and this DOES work, BUT a) I have to do this *every time*, and b) Github will kill this option in a few months time.

In summary:

- From Windows, I can push my PowerShell projects without issues, Git for Windows handles my authorization (so I don't need to input username/password every time I do a push).
- From WSL Ubuntu, when I push my bash/python projects, Git for Windows credential manager pops open (every time) to ask for my username/password, but then completely fails to authorise (`Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt`) and I have to manually input username/password to git in bash (every time).

Any advice on this would be really appreciated, as it's frustrating to not have the seamless WSL operation that I've read should be possible, and even worse, all of this will break in a few months when Github prevent sending credentials from the console.

Comment: This won't answer your question, IK that's why I'm putting in comments instead of answers... You can use GitHub CLI if you're facing issues like that. Install it in WSL and it won't ask you OAuth every time.

Comment: Ok, I think you are talking about this? https://dev.to/sisodiya2421/get-github-cli-in-wsl2-4d6n I've never used it, but this could be good, I only ever use Github, so this might be all that I need.

Comment: Yep, that's the one!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from /usr/bin/git-credential-manager change, you need to run :

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.gitconfig
[credential]
    helper = manager
EOF
```

It should work now. If not, try to use `/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe` instead of /usr/bin/git

Comment: I had already put that into `~/.gitconfig` (forgot to mention it above) so that still doesn't fix it. However, your idea to use git.exe from `/mnt/c` *does* work (thanks for that), so I can at least alias the `git.exe` from `/mnt/c` with your workaround. I'm still completely stumped why `git-credential-manager.exe` won't work with `/usr/bin/git` though in the way that people say it should. 